# MEAN authentication strategies without user accounts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authentication, express

I'm building a simple MEAN survey app (think strawpoll). I would like people to be able to use my app without creating an account (I will implement a captcha on the form submission page).

However, right now anyone can just throw requests at the api directly, and I would like to secure it. Also, I would like to make sure each visitor can only vote once (I know this isn't 100% possible).

What sort of strategy can I use to secure my app? I'm thinking it's going to have to be some sort of session, but all of the strategies I see in tutorials seem to require some sort of user account.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You can limit CORS to specific domains, and then use a CSRF token to ensure it came from a website form, and limit requests to one ip address

Comment: Perfect.

I'm not familiar with CORS or CSRF so I guess I have some reading to do.

Thank you!

Comment: the api can use captha, then you just need to worry about re-votes. also, if you use captha, you don't need a CSRF token... also, CORS won't stop form submits from other sites, so it's of little value. also, limiting it to a single IP is a bad idea; whole dorms often use a single IP via NAT, and one user can have 5 IPs in 5 mins on a smartphone...

Comment: in terms of double voting, the simplest solution is a cookie or localStorage or window.name or all three. sure, some folks can get around that, but some folks can get around just about anything. if you use more than just a one-click fix, like cookies and window.name, or localStorage and flashStorage, you will overcome the attempts of at least 75% of the small group of folks who will try to skirt the rules. if it needs to be 100%, you need accounts.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot Dan, I think I have a good idea of where to go with this. I just did some reading on how to implement captcha and I think it should work well for securing the api.

I'll probably go with some sort of session storage for the double voting, there are just too many problems when using ip's.


Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @dandavis learned something today, thank you